# Display 2 inputs in the same line

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular8

I have this code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <div fxFlex="50%">
     <input
        matInput
        formControlName="field1"
        required
        type="number"
        min="0"
     />
     <span matSuffix>h</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="50%">
     <input
        matInput
        formControlName="field2"
        required
        type="number"
        min="0"
     />
     <span matSuffix>min</span>
  </div>
  <mat-icon matSuffix>access_time</mat-icon>
  <mat-error>Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

The display is like this :

[image]

I want to put all items in one line, I tried with display block, inline-block, but is not working as expected.

Comment: Try setting `display:flex` for `<mat-form-field>`

Comment: display is worse.......

Comment: can you make it in stackbitz or codesandbox ?

Comment: either `dispaly: flex` or dont wrap them in div and maintain the normal inline behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each input with `mat-form-field` individually and now wrap the both `mat-form-field` with `div` also apply `display: flex` style.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <!-- Field 1 -->
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
           matInput
           formControlName="field1"
           required
           type="number"
           min="0"
           />
    <span matSuffix>h</span>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>access_time</mat-icon>
    <mat-error>Required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- Field 2 -->
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
           matInput
           formControlName="field2"
           required
           type="number"
           min="0"
           />
    <span matSuffix>min</span>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>access_time</mat-icon>
    <mat-error>Required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

And if you want both `mat-form-field` to take `50%` of the available width, then add `flex-basis: 100%` to `mat-form-field`.